# Please explain the difference in the order of naming Tzelafchad's daughters

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mattos, masei

When naming the daughters of Tzelafchad in [Bemidbar 26:33](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=362&hilite=) and when they approached Moshe with the inheritance question in [Bemidbar 27:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=372&hilite=) the order is:

Machla, Noah, Chaglah, Milka, Tirtzah

When they are married, as state in [Bemidbar 36:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=466&hilite=) the order is:

Machla, Tirtzah, Chagla, Mika, Noah

Why the change in order?

Perhaps, the first two orders them in birth order - oldest to youngest and the 3rd list is the order in which they were married?

Comment: Also Joshua 17:3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gemara Bava Basra 120a [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.120a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that one list is according to their age, and the other is based on their wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that is R. Avraham ibn Ezra's assertion when [commenting on Bemidbar 36:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Numbers.36.11?lang=bi):
הזכירן הכתוב בתחלה כאשר נולדו (במדבר כ"ז:א'), ועתה כאשר נשאו לאנשים בתחלה.